# How to get inbetween jquery file upload options.done callback?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget

I'm using: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Basically, I need to be able to save the current `done` callback and call it in my own `done` callback which is unbelievably complicated (I'm not familiar with jquery ui widgets).

Here's the code I'm trying to get to work to no avail:

```
var $el = $('#fileupload');
$el.fileupload();
var olddone = $el.fileupload('option', 'done');
$el.fileupload('option', 'done', function(e, data) {
    data = ... manipulate data ...;
    return olddone(e, data);
});
```

I've tried various variations on the theme:

```
return olddone.call(this, e, data);
```

and:

```
return olddone.call($el.data('fileupload'), e, data);
```

and:

```
return olddone.call($el[0], e, data);
```

And all errors basically tell me that `this` is not correct and the context is not right for all the following calls.  What am I doing wrong?  How can I more or less **subclass** a specific callback but still use/call the original callback?

What's worse, is that copying the source of the `done` callback in place of `olddone` (instead of saving a reference and calling it) doesn't seem to work either.

What is `this` in the context of a jQuery UI Widget options function?  Why is this so convoluted?  What am I missing?

**EDIT:**
After reading some widget documentation, it seems that all the methods are always called with the widget instance as `this`, so why wouldn't the following work right?

```
olddone.call($el.data('fileupload'), e, data)
```

**UPDATE:**

I'm trying to preserve the `done:` callback in `options` that are here: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/75d11179fd9c248c061c8eb428782bb556c8db0a/js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js#L139

Comment: I can't really understand your problem,  but: where does the original done callback come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out that I was misusing the data passed in and I really just needed to use it correctly.  This is the final code I needed to get this working.

```
var olddone = $el.data('fileupload').options.done;
$el.fileupload('option', 'done', function(e, data) {
    data.result = ... manipulate data ...;
    return olddone.call(this, e, data);
});
```

The `olddone.call(this, ...)` turned out to still be necessary for some reason.  Not sure why `this` was inherited from the current context and was instead undefined.